How to remove Titlebar in CSS for a selected theme in Cinnamon
I am currently customizing a theme in Cinnamon and I would like to remove the titlebar from windows. Could you please guide me on how to achieve this using CSS? Specifically, I need to know which CSS classes or elements to modify and what properties to set.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
Best regards,
Tom

Please [edit] your question and tell us what css files you are modifying. Ideally, add them to the question as code (use the {} button) or, if they're too large, upload them somewhere and link them. But at least give us their path on your system for those of us who use Cinnamon and can find them on our own systems.
